# what to do get a two digit number by using datepart () in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use `DatePart` to return a two digit hour. I would like to see `01, 02, 03, ...10, 11, 12` for the hours. How can I do this?

if I entered query as,

```
select DATEPART(hour,'1900-01-01 07:45:00.010')
```

then I am getting answer `7`. I need to get answer as `07`.

Comment: Then why did you tag as MySQL as well?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this for MySql or from [SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) -

```
select FORMAT(DATEPART(hour,'1900-01-01 07:45:00.010'),'00')
```

For SQL Server before 2012 -

```
select right('0' + DATEPART(hour,'1900-01-01 07:45:00.010'),2)
```

Comment: I think this works only with strings. The datepart has to be converted to varchar.

Comment: The version you show for versions of SQL Server before 2012 is incorrect.  `DATEPART()` always returns `int`.  You can't add an `int` to a `char`.  The correct statement should be `SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, '1900-01-01 07:45:00.010') AS VARCHAR),2)`

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't get the above* solutions to work against SQL Server 2008.

What worked for me was:

```
select right('0' + convert(varchar,DATEPART(hour,'1900-01-01 07:45:00.010')),2)
```

returns

```
07
```

*all the SQL Server solutions above returned "7" for me, not "07".  Instead I used the `convert(varchar...` to make the "0" + "07" a concatenation of string to string, not string to numeric.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL,

```
SELECT LPAD(thing_to_pad, 2, '0')
```

In MS SQL (I think - I don't use it):

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + thing_to_pad, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function (supported in Sql Server 2012) -

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '1900-01-01 07:45:00.010';
SELECT FORMAT(@d, 'hh' )
>07
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL

```
select right('0' + DATEPART(hour,'1900-01-01 07:45:00.010'),2)
```

This is works

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this for mssql;

```
 RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(dd, date)), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

RIGHT() with CONCAT() conceptually makes more sense to me.

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT('0' , DATEPART(MM,  ar.ReportDate)),2)
```